# No junction box on exterior light?

Tags: electrical

I just purchased a new built home and I was going to replace these exterior sconces when I noticed that none of them had a junction box, just like pictures below.

My initial thoughts were if this is up to code. I asked the builder if no junction box was normal and he said that the fixture is direct wired to the mounting hardware and that's all that was needed.

Is this true or should I be concerned?

*BTW, this is on fiber cement siding (hardie board)*

[image]

[image]

Comment: It’s common but not proper nor to code

Comment: Many wall pack lights that have the junction made inside the fixture do not require a box at all as the fixture is the box.

Comment: Many thanks for the comments. I'm thinking about replacing these lights now with some with a pancake junction box built in. I think that's the way to go. In general, I feel like I should confront the builder on this.

Answer (score 2):

Lots of fixtures or canopies are made to attach directly to cable or conduit, with integral cable clamps or knockouts for suitable (listed, rated...) cable clamps or conduit entry.  This one is not.

The NEC requires light fixtures be listed, and used as intended by the manufacturer.  The metal ring in your photo is not for direct surface mounting, it's made to go on a box, using it for a surface mount is not compliant.

There are a few other code provisions that could be problematic, protection from abrasion and water seepage, etc.  They didn't even wrap the ground wire around the screw.  But the main thing you need here is a box.  Retrofitting it will be a bit of a project.

The box doesn't necessarily fix everything;  the fixture must be suitable (listed, rated for outdoor use, etc.) and made to mount on the type of box that you install.

Answer (score 0):

To my understanding this is 1000% not ok by any codes.  (Disclaimer, I'm an electrical engineer, not an electrician)

So far as I know, all wire junctions need to be completely enclosed in a non-flammable box.  This clearly is not.

There is no electrical shock hazard here.  It's a fire hazard.  If the flammability spec of your wall is known, MAYBE this is OK but a general contractor is not in a position to make that call --- It would have to be made by a licensed PE (professional engineer).

https://www.prospertx.gov/wp-content/uploads/NFPA-NEC-Guide-to-Wire-Box-Installation-01-10-17.pdf

314.19 Boxes Enclosing Flush Devices. Boxes used to enclose flush devices shall be of such design that the devices will
be completely enclosed on back and sides and substantial support for the devices will be provided. Screws for supporting
the box shall not be used in attachment of the device contained therein.

Your local building inspector may have a difference of opinion and think this is OK.   Of course, if you contact him/her, you might be opening Pandoras box.

In reality, the risk is pretty small.    Maybe 1:1,000,000 odds of an issue.   But the codes are written with the expectation there will be a million installations and NONE should cause somebody to die.

Comment: Since the box is on a non flammable surface there is no risk of fire, we don’t know if there is a box behind the hardi plank siding. My state doesn’t require a engineer at all a supervising electrician can do any plan, design layout and install of electrical systems industrial, commercial or residential.

Comment: ^^^  Absolutely in most states the layout and plans can be done by a licensed electrician.  To do so, it would be assumed they use all certified and rated components. 
 I'm saying that investigating and certifying the flame and temperature rating of the siding material meets NEC requirements for junction boxes is not within their sphere of expertise and they should not make that call (though I'm sure that doesn't stop 98% of 'em from doing so).  Only a degreed engineer trained in this area would be qualified to do that.

Comment: There are also requirements for minimum wire pigtail length in a junction box (6", which these clearly do not meet) and cubic-inch of space (which this also likely doesn't meet -- chart here: https://3.bp.blogspot.com/-FQQwASKRuKc/UbWtHU6VAEI/AAAAAAAAIfA/0cKaQQ4i85c/s640/TABLE+314.16%2528A%2529.JPG)     from here:  https://electrical-inspector.blogspot.com/2013/06/electrical-boxes.html

Comment: ^^^^   All that "IMO" of course  ;)    Reference previous disclaimer and take it all with however many grains of salt you wish  :)

Comment: The supervising electrician in my state can do anything! A engineer can do! Plus the install that most engineer usually can not do. Code actually requires 6” from the back of the box so if there is a box behind the hardi plank it would probably meet code (this is quite common in my area but yes a box is required to be flush with the flammable material.

Comment: LOL    I like you already Ed   ;)     I'm gonna agree to disagree that they can do "anything" ... Laying out plans yes, but that's because the plans have to abide by rules previously defined by engineers.   My only point was this is a materials question, not a layout/design question, and "technically" if one has not studied the material sciences at a graduate level (which I am pretty sure is not a course in any electricians program), then one does not have the background to read and understand, and make judgement calls on the application of materials.

Comment: In your state, can a carpenter submit plans for a building project without needing PE signoff???  I doubt it very much.   Why would that be?   Said carpenter would have built MANY houses, no?

Comment: No previously plans needed you can continue to be arrogant but a supervising electrician can design from scratch! Layout from scratch and install any electrical installation in Oregon! We just built an entire mill with only 1 signature on all electrical plans no engineer was needed, this is why Oregon has one of the hardest licensing requirements. I said nothing about carpentry but an individual can design their own building I did I did need an engineering stamp on 1 foundation wall as it was 12’ below grade other than that 1 stamp my 2 story 3 bay wide building was approved by the the BCD

Comment: I'm sorry if you think I'm being arrogant.  I was trying to be friendly, guess I failed.  Getting in arguments with strangers is not my thing, so this ends now.  But I will say I've always found it odd when blue-collar craftsmen assume that getting an engineering degree removes ones common sense and mechanical aptitude.  In New York (where I live), you have to get PE stamps on EVERYTHING structural BTW.   Classic example we study in school where an engineering decision was made by a non engineer, results were fatal.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyatt_Regency_walkway_collapse

Comment: Well I did find the code for you for oregon (working as a contractor allows a supervising electrician to do anything) the bond is expensive and I found it easier on my body to work in industrial plants ORS 918-282-0140 and your link had nothing to do with electrical.

Answer (score 0):

Should be ok running the wire like that, but not the connection.  You could install a shallow "pancake" electrical box on the wall and then the wire would be within the box.  (e.g. https://www.lowes.com/pd/RACO-1-Gang-Gray-Metal-New-Work-Shallow-Ceiling-Pans-Ceiling-Electrical-Box/1099827)

Comment: Wouldn't they need a weatherproof (Bell) box in this situation?